# Return value of object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following statement:

```js
const queue = [
  {name: "Click2Call"}
]
return queue.name
```

This returns `null`.

How can I fix it to return the object name?

Comment: `queue` is an array, you have to access the position before get the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? This

> ```
> queue:[{"name": "Click2Call"}]
> ```

is syntactically correct, but doesn't do anything. If you are trying to create a variable called `queue` you need to declare the variable with `const` or `let` (or `var`) and use the assignment operator `=`. For example:

```
const queue = [{"name": "Click2Call"}]
```

But this is also an array which doesn't have a `name` property. You need to access the first element of the array. For example:

```
return queue[0].name
```

Comment: Tks man! I created constant and convert Object.assign, its worked! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an array with a key.
You can try:
`return queue[0].name`

But that is not robust and can fail if the array is empty or if the 0 indexed value doesn't have that key.